# iPhone: onscroll event does not stop firing (Javascript only)

Tags: ios, iphone, onscroll

I am working on a Grails application that includes two 2 iframes.

The first iframe is a control panel / menu. The second iframe is a webpage.

My problem is that on iPhone when the page loads the onscroll event does not stop firing. It is called like 200 times or so per second even though I don't interact with the page. On Android it works just fine.

Has anybody encountered this before? I've been searching the internet for similar problems but could not find anything.

Comment: scrollviewdidscroll will be called multiple times

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that I need a javascript solution.